# WPF Combobox Binding Entity Framework

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, binding, combobox, datagrid

This is the class that the Entity Framework created from the Database.

```
namespace QuickTest
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class laender
    {
        public int idLaender { get; set; }
        public string EU { get; set; }
        public string FIBUPrefixKunde { get; set; }
        public string FIBUPrefixLieferant { get; set; }
        public string ISO2 { get; set; }
        public string ISO3 { get; set; }
        public string Land_DE { get; set; }
        public string Land_EN { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Vorwahl { get; set; }
        public string KFZ { get; set; }
        public string TLD { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> NeukundenLimitABC { get; set; }              
    }
}
```

And I simply want to show those values in a Datagrid (thats working)

But I want the EU property to be a combobox with just 2 simple options "Yes" and "No"
So there is no foreign Key to some other Table or something. When I am binding  the SelectedItem to EU it just shows nothing and I dont know why

Here is the XAML of the DataGrid

```
<DataGrid x:Name="laenderDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="58,48,59,72" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="eUColumn" Header="EU" Width="SizeToHeader">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding EU}">
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="YES"/>
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="NO"/>
                    </ComboBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="fIBUPrefixKundeColumn" Binding="{Binding FIBUPrefixKunde}" Header="FIBUPrefix Kunde" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="fIBUPrefixLieferantColumn" Binding="{Binding FIBUPrefixLieferant}" Header="FIBUPrefix Lieferant" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="idLaenderColumn" Binding="{Binding idLaender}" Header="id Laender" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="iSO2Column" Binding="{Binding ISO2}" Header="ISO 2" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="iSO3Column" Binding="{Binding ISO3}" Header="ISO 3" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="kFZColumn" Binding="{Binding KFZ}" Header="KFZ" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="land_DEColumn" Binding="{Binding Land_DE}" Header="Land DE" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="land_ENColumn" Binding="{Binding Land_EN}" Header="Land EN" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="neukundenLimitABCColumn" Binding="{Binding NeukundenLimitABC}" Header="Neukunden Limit ABC" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="tLDColumn" Binding="{Binding TLD}" Header="TLD" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="vorwahlColumn" Binding="{Binding Vorwahl}" Header="Vorwahl" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

There is no binding error or any other error it's just not showing

**EDIT**

I got it to work I had to set the Binding to SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath to Content because I want the COntent of the Comboboxitem

```
SelectedValuePath="Content" SelectedValue="{Binding EU}
```